# Overloading Functions with Pattern Matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, overloading

Hello fellow Haskell Fans!

All my questions are about the -- OVERLOADED(?) FUNCTION -- part, I included the rest for completeness.

1. I was wondering if it makes sense to use Pattern Matching to Overload my function **order** like I did in my example below.
2. I was also wondering if the first function with the function call "checkBalance balance" in the first version of the **order** function always gets executerd (because I didn't sepcify a pattern for it) or never (because all the patterns of Food are covered in the functions below).

Thanks in advance from a beginner :)

```
-- TYPE DECLARATIONS --
data Spice = Regular | Medium | Hot
data Base  = Noodles | Rice
data Meat  = Duck | Chicken | Pork
data Sauce = Tomato | Meatballs | Carbonara

data Food  = Indian Spice | Pasta Sauce | Chinese Base Meat

data DeliveryOption = Pickup | Delivery

data DeliveryTime = Immediate | Later

type CreditBalance = Int

data Order = O Food DeliveryOption CreditBalance

data OrderStatus = Success | Pending | Declined

-- OVERLOADED(?) FUNCTION --
order :: (Order, CreditBalance) -> OrderStatus
order (O {}, balance)
  | not (checkBalance balance ) = Declined
  | ...

order (O Indian {} _ _, _)
  | ...

order (O Pasta {} _ _, _)
  | ...

order (O Chinese {} _ _, _)
  | ...

-- ANOTHER FUNCTION --
checkBalance :: CreditBalance -> Bool
checkBalance balance
  | balance > 100 = True
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: `order` is not overloaded. The individual definitions are just syntactic sugar for something like `order x = case x of (O {}, balance) -> ...`.

Comment: so what i wrote is basically a switch statement covered in syntactic sugar? Is there a more elegant way to branch the different orders with specified types of food?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```hs
-- OVERLOADED(?) FUNCTION --
order :: (Order, CreditBalance) -> OrderStatus
order (O {}, balance)
  | not (checkBalance balance ) = Declined
  | ...
```

The above pattern will cover every case and anything below it will never have the opportunity to check.

Reason is that `Order` has only one constructor, namely `O`, and `(O {})`, matches all possible arguments to the `O` constructor. The other member of the tuple is just a simple `Int` which always matches.

Since patterns are matched from top to bottom and the first that matches is chosen, the ordering of their definition in code is important. If you put the broadest possible pattern at the top, the more specific ones below will never have the opportunity to match.

As for overloading function, I can think of how one could (ab)use pattern matching to imitate function overloading as in OOP, but then you would also need to (ab)use data declarations and the whole type system to bend them to conform to such an idea and this would just make things worse.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that the first order function is exhaustive (just for my understanding)? Would it make more sense to delete that first function and checkBalance in each function where the food type of the order is matched individually ?

Comment: yes, you are absolute correct. The first pattern is exhaustive. And yes, I would go from narrow patterns to broader ones. Look at it as an `if elif elif elif else` construct where the first branch that is true runs and the last one is the all encompassing pattern (if the ones before haven't covered everything already).

Comment: okay that makes sense! Is there a more elegant way to handle this branching than i did with pattern matching, or is this good practice? I was struggeling finding a solution for this specific program because Food is a type "wrapped" in the type order if you understand what I mean.

Comment: I think pattern matching is perfect for this case.

Comment: The first case isn't exhaustive unless there's a catchall guard like `| otherwise`. If the guards don't cover all cases then the other patterns will be considered. I think OP wants to express "if you don't have enough money or some other cuisine-independent thing goes wrong, then handle that first; otherwise, fall through to cuisine-specific handling", which will work fine as OP wrote it.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything really wrong with that function definition.

Function clauses are tried in order, so that first branch with `checkBalance` will always be tried first, and the next guard, and so on, and if none of the guards of the first group is matched, then the next group will be tried (`O Indian {} _ _`).

If the guards of the first group were exhaustive, then the other branches below would not be reachable, which would mean something is wrong but it's hard to say more without more details.

Comment: Well there are no more details in the parts with a guard followed by dots (```| ...```) because I wanted to know how the order of execution works before I implement any further stuff. So if I wanted to implement some stuff for each order function depending on the Food type individually it would make more sense to delete the first order function and checkBalance in each order function individually right?